# Router rendering the component on the same page rather than rendering in a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Router is rendering the page on the same page than to generate a new page. What might be the problem? Whenever I click the link **Polls** , it renders the page only there but the URL is shown as changed in the browser.

Polls.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class Polls extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Polls Page</h1>
                <p>This is Polls Page </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {Polls}
```

Choices.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Polls} from "./Polls";

class ShowChoice extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <Link to='/polls'>Polls</Link>
                <Route path='/polls' component={Polls} />
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

And the `ShowChoice` is rendered inside `APP`

flow of rendering is like

```
index>APP>ShowChoices
```

**(link to the Polls inside ShowChoices)**

and my `APP.js` is

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ShowChoice formResult={this.state.result} />
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: This is because you have included `Router` in `App` component only, so whenever you click on any `Link`,it will render that component in the place where you have added the `Route`.

Comment: To make this work, you need to separate out the Route's and add Route for your App component too.

Comment: sorry! not able to comprehend. Could you please provide me with some example? I have included my **App.js** file too

Comment: Hi Deshwal, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your `Route` in `ShowChoice` component. Your `ShowChoice` component is then added to `App` component.

So whenever yo click the `Link`, your URL will get changed but it will render the component in `App` component only. So your `App` component's content is also visible to you.

To make it feel like you get new page when you click the `Link`, you need to combine all the `Route` at top level, may be in a separate component,

```
const Routers = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/polls" component={Polls} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

So this will render `App` component by default on first render, which will render `ShowChoice` component added in `App` component and you will see `Link` for your `Polls` component.

Now clicking on `Link`, you will get new page of your `Polls` component.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bjqawo)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change path and use `exact` like that

```
<Route exact path="/polls" component={Polls}/>
```

More info: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md