# React Router not loading specific component and removing all other components too

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning the basics of React Router. So what I'm making right now has a navigation bar on top and two buttons below this top bar. What I want is for the a table or something of the sort to show up when I press one of the buttons. 
The problem is that when I click the button, the URL changes but the all the components vanish. Even the component I want displayed doesn't show and the other components (which ideally should stay) also disappear. 
What am I doing wrong here? The code is as follows :-

```
const Site = () =>
    <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid row">
                    <div className="offset-3 col-sm-4">
                            <Link to="/A">
                                    <Button value="A"/>
                            </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                            <Link to="/B">
                                    <Button value="B"/>
                            </Link>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <Route path="/B" component={B}/>
                 </div>
    </React.Fragment>

export default Site;
```

The Site page has the URL '/Site'.

Edit:

Just thought I'd mention the structure a bit. So for now I have a page with a button. Clicking this button should load the a component (called Base with URL '/Site') which is calling the TopBar and Site components. 
Then I have these two buttons - A and B which have their respective URLs.

Comment: Do you have separate routes? Can you show the routes?

Comment: @ravibagul91 separate routes as in?

Comment: How you are using Routes? Check example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788712/router-rendering-the-component-on-the-same-page-rather-than-rendering-in-a-new-p/57789892#57789892)

Comment: @ravibagul91 the structure is something like this: button click>Site>B
I want a separate URL to be loaded on clicking B and I think that is removing whatever was present in the Site page with the '/Site' URL

Comment: Then try this `<Link to="/Site/B">`

Comment: Can you add your code on codesandbox?https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @ravibagul91 that worked. Thanks!